# How to loop through all users in the database and apply a role

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a loop that loops through each users data in my events table in the database and applies the role of suspended if the amount of rows returned is a multiple of 12.

Here's what I have created but it doesn't seem to work;

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    for( $x = 1; $x < 300; $x++ ){
        $count = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_events WHERE user_id = "'.$x.'"' ); 

        if ($count % 12 == 0){ 
            $user = new WP_User( $x );
            $user->add_role( 'suspended' );
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @ChinLeung the user role of 'suspended' is not being applied when $count is a multiple of 12

Comment: shouldn't your loop start at 0? check you aren't updating the next guy

Comment: why do you only suspend guys with 12, 24, 36, 48 rows, etc? surely you just mean over 12?

Comment: @delboy1978uk no it has to be a multiple of 12 the user gets to submit 12 events then has to get a new membership. I'm just having to update old data here

Comment: `get_results()` returns an array or rows !!! Do you mean `count($count) % 12`

Comment: Your `$count` variable isn't a number so your `if` condition will never be met: [get_results()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) returns array|object|null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `get_results` returns an array. Therefore, you are using an array to calculate the modulo, so it's always going to return `1`.

To fix this, you can change your condition to:

```
if (count($count) % 12 == 0) {
    // Your code...
}
```

For more information: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/